# using sourcetree and gitflow to do a release

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I am new to using `sourcetree` and my repository is in `bitbucket`.

If i am using the git-flow to do release do i need to have write permission on both master and develop because when i click the finish release button it creates changes to my local master and develop and i am not able to push these as i don't have write permission.

I can only make pull request. So i am not sure the sequence of events i need to do.
I have tried to create pull request from release to master and also release to develop, approve and merge but then when i click finish release to add the tag i still get same issue.

Comment: what is your question? git-flow is just a kind of workflow/process for git, if you don't have permission to push to develop or master it's not linked to git flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way but by manually do the steps that a `git flow release finish` is doing:

Here is the summary:

1. Merge `release` branch to `master` branch.
2. Delete the `release` branch.
3. Tag the `master` branch with the right version.
4. Merge the `master` branch to `develop`.

Git-Flow is not strict whether you use the `git flow release finish` or not. It is intelligent enough to know that when a release branch is already merge to master and develop branch and that the release branch is already deleted, Git Flow automatically recognizes that the release branch is finished. Same goes with feature branches.

Here is how you should do it:

1. Create a pull request from `release` => `master` branch.
2. Wait until the pull request is approved and completed.
3. Once the pull request is completed make sure that the `release` branch is deleted.
4. Tag the new `master` branch with the right release version.
5. Then, create another pull request `master` => `develop`.
6. Wait until the pull request is approved and completed.
7. Then pull all changes.

With these steps, you keep the pull request and the git-flow process at the same time.